# Setup Facebook app in other language

Tags: facebook

I created a facebook app. It's in English. However I need it to be displayed in German (only if possible) by default. I went through the facebook manuals and, unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

Your thoughts?

UPDATE: Let me show what I want.[image: an application]

I (as an author) need it to be displayed absolutely in German, even any standard facebook label. I already set local to Deutsch (`Setting->Advanced->Locale`) but it's still in English.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find what?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

*Added for question update:*

Facebook:

> If you're rendering a social plugin in an IFrame, Facebook
>   automatically translates the text because it's based on the viewing
>   user's locale.
>
> If you're using XFBML, you need to load the JavaScript SDK in the
>   appropriate locale for your site. For example, if your site is in
>   Spanish, reference this script:
>
> //connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js

Comment: It describes how to add other languages.